# configuring ext:solr for a phonebook

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-9.x

I want solr to index a phonebook.
I use the configuration from the installation script coming with the extension and have cores for all languages, though we only use the german core ('core_de`) as the page only is german.

I use fe_users with soem additional fields for the phonebook items.

my configuration is like:

```
plugin.tx_solr {
    index {
        queue {
            :
            phonebook = 1
            phonebook {
                table = fe_users
                fields {
                    content = COA
                        :
                    title = COA
                        :
                    :
                    last_name_stringS = last_name
                    last_name1_phoneticS = last_name
                    last_name2_textExactS = last_name
                    last_name3_textNgramS = last_name
                    :
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

For a nice display of result I build COAs for `content` and `title` where the full name respective address is build up.
For having different possibilities I define multiple version of the sur_name for indexing.

My Problem is the search for names as these do not match the usual stemming.

There is an entry with the surname `Dankelmann`.
Searching for `danke` gives this record as a result.
Searching for `dankel` gives no result

`TYPO3`: 9.5.16
`ext:solr`: 10.0.1
`solr`: 8.5.0

Comment: what field type is applied for your field?

Comment: the fieldtype is given by the appendix, so I tried different versions.

Comment: need to know its fieldType details like tokenizer and filters of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I defined all the variants of the fields I forgot to add these fields to the list of queried fields.
So the solution was just:

```
plugin.tx_solr {
    :
    search {
        :
        query {
            queryFields = content^40.0, last_name^30.0, last_name1_phoneticS^20.0, last_name3_textNgramS^20.0, first_name_stringS^20.0, username_stringS^15.0, title^5.0, tagsH1^5.0, description^4.0, tagsH2H3^3.0, tagsH4H5H6^2.0, keywords^2.0, tagsInline^1.0, abstract^1.0, subtitle^1.0, navtitle^1.0, author^1.0
        }
    }
}
```